# Как получить значение ключа в массиве?

Tags: php

```
$array = [
  ['id' => 12, 'title' => 'Заголовок'],
  ['id' => 15, 'title' => 'Заголовок 2'],
  ['id' => 16, 'title' => 'Заголовок 3'],
  ...
];
```

Как получить `title` зная только `id`?

Желательно без `foreach`

Comment: Да вы издеваетесь, что ли? С такими базовыми вопросами изучали вообще основы PHP, базовые методы, самостоятельно пытались найти решение? Ну, ей богу, за такие вопросы надо в детский сад PHP отправлять! Мозгами надо шевелить, а не по каждой проблеме бежать сюда, в надежде что тут за вас её решат. Ставлю вопросу жирный минус.

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov, как такое сделать без foreach? через foreach такое легко сделать, но оно очень медленное на большом массиве, даже при использовании continue

Comment: Без итерации по массиву такое не сделать. И что там медленного? У тебя что ли миллиард записей в массиве?

Comment: @u_mulder, количество около 80 трл записей

Comment: Массив на 6 гигабайт? Откуда он? А главное - __зачем__ ты получаешь все записи?

Comment: обработка из локального сервера

Comment: Ты что-то делаешь не так. Если это записи в БД, то `SELECT WHERE id = ` возвращает одну нужную запись.

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = 15;
$title = $array[array_search($id, array_column($array, 'id'))]['title']; 
echo title;
```

Но это не спасёт, если у вас триллион записей :D
Как правильно указали в комментариях, выбирайте из БД сразу нужные записи, если необходимо.

---

Ну а в целом без цикла среди таких записей не выбрать. При совпадении записи надо прерывать цикла, а не делать `continue`, чтобы не делать лишних итераций

```
$id = 15;
$title = '';

foreach($array as $item) {
    if ($item['id'] === $id) {
        $title = $item['title'];
        break;
    }
}
```

---

Вот если бы у вас массив сразу был бы проиндексирован идентификаторами, как пример:

```
$array = [
  12 => ['id' => 12, 'title' => 'Заголовок'],
  15 => ['id' => 15, 'title' => 'Заголовок 2'],
  16 => ['id' => 16, 'title' => 'Заголовок 3'],
  ...
];
```

Тогда без цикла было бы достать очень легко:

```
$id = 15;
$title =  $array[$id]['title'];
```